# xfce4, xfce4-appmenu-plugin takes a lot of CPU

Tags: xfce, appmenu

I am on Ubuntu with XFCE. I installed `xfce4-appmenu-plugin`. My cooler is quite active from this time, so I checked what is going on and I was surprised by this.

[image]

Should this plugin really take a lot of CPU as in this example? Or is there some problem on my side?

My laptop configuration.

```
AMD Ryzen 5 4500U with Radeon Graphic, 16GB RAM
```

Thank you.

Comment: This is [a known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vala-panel-appmenu/+bug/1838586) that has been around for a couple of years. I’ve not seen a viable solution for this on modern Ubuntu installations … and the non-viable ones are suboptimal 